# How can i see the total size of the ViewState by using Fiddler?

Tags: .net, asp.net, http, viewstate, fiddler

Where can I see the total size of ViewState out of the total size of the Response (value in bytes in the Body column) in Fiddler 2?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could simply copy-paste the value of the `__VIEWSTATE` hidden-field (using "view source" in the browser, works without fiddler) to a new text-file and check the size of this file.

Comment: Or Copy/Paste the view state, hit CTRL+E, and look at the title of the dialog (pasting in the state if needed). The title shows the length of the text in the top-box. Alternatively, you could write a few lines of FiddlerScript to automatically compute the ViewState size and stick it in a column in the UI.

Comment: `$("input[id=__VIEWSTATE][type=hidden]").val().length` will give you the size in bytes. (learnt this today). LOL.

Answer (score 2):

You can neXpert plug-in for fiddler available in the MS ACE team blog. It creates report for you with Viewstate details and lot of other performance recommendation. You can also set threshold values for web page statistics.

Answer (score 1):

There is a very nice plugin for Firefox that allows you to directly see the size of the viewstate in your browser: [Firefox Viewstate Size Plugin 1.0.3](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5956/).

Answer (score 0):

A post from [4GuysFromRolla](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020140121/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/091510-1.aspx) will help you to calculate the size of view state, I am not sure if you can do that in fiddler without writing a brand new extension for fiddler

Answer (score 0):

I just created a Fiddler Extension that helps do this:

http://blog.bareweb.eu/2010/11/http-debugging-fiddler-tip-5-managed-code-extension/

It also outputs other stats for the HTML page, and you can see the Fiddler Log tab for detailed numeric stats.