# How to debug a Fiddler Extension

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, fiddler

I am trying to write a fiddler extension that implements `IAutoTamper` but nothing is happening.  What I would like is a way to debug the extension so that I could step through and find out what exactly is failing.

I have already tried attaching Visual Studio to the Fiddler.exe both using the menu item and using the tips suggested by [AndyBareWeb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/516179/andybareweb) on his blog post in response to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4194174/how-can-i-see-the-total-size-of-the-viewstate-by-using-fiddler).

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Attaching with Visual Studio should work fine. What specifically happened?

The #1 cause of the problem you've described is that you've failed to make your class public, or you failed to properly add the Fiddler.RequiredVersionAttribute to your assembly.

Inside Fiddler, you should also type the following in the QuickExec box below the session list:

> prefs set fiddler.debug.extensions.verbose True

...and then restart Fiddler. You can find some additional debug information in the LOG tab.

Comment: The problem was actually that I had the assembly attribute inside a  namespace instead of in the global namespace and therefore it didn't find it.

Comment: That setting really helped for a different bug I was having. Fiddler can't load .NET 4.0 dlls.

Comment: Correct. The step-by-step tutorial at http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/dev/IFiddlerExtension.asp might help.

Comment: Is there any plan to support loading .NET 4.0 dlls in the near future?

Comment: Use the .NET v4 version of Fiddler, which has been available for download for a few months now.